# Cron command to run a controller function on a given url?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a route i.e `Route::get('abc/xyz', 'AbcController@xyz')`. How to write a cron command in cpanel to execute the controller function xyz()?

And the `xyz()` function is accepting a request i.e `xyz(Request $r){if($_REQUEST['step']=='1'){...}}`

Cron job option & Command in cpanel :

```
05 16 * * * wget http://www.abc.in/laravelAppFolder/abc/xyz?step=1
```

How to write the above command correctly to run the controller function?

Comment: What is not working with your current one? The request doesn't get to your service?

Comment: Does it work when you access the URL manually?

Comment: Yeah, the function is not running... but if i manually type the url then its running the controller function...

Comment: Yes, it is working when i access the url manually...

Comment: Could you try to use cURL? `05 16 * * * curl -s '<your url>' > /dev/null`

Comment: 05 16 * * * curl -s '<your url>' > /dev/null -after url  '> ' is there?

Comment: I have checked but it's not working.

Comment: Could you try the curl in terminal and provide the result? That could help to stop guessing and find a solution. Url you provided is unreachable and returns 404.
`> /dev/null` is used to prevent creating any temp files and redirect all the output to /dev/null

Comment: From terminal its (curl -s <myurl> ) working... Can you please tell me how to set current time to run cron ? i think problem with the time and date. i want to run cron now.

Comment: can you please expalin this command : wget -O - -q -t 1 --timeout=90000 <url>